# Count values in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables = `subjects` and `stats`.

```
  -- subjects --             
------------------          
|  id  | name    |          
------------------         
|  1  |  subjecta |        
|  2  |  subjectb |       
|  3  |  subjectc |         
|  4  |  subjectd |         
|  5  |  subjecte |        
|  6  |  subjectf |        
|  7  |  subjectg |      
|  8  |  subjecth |         
|  9  |  subjecte |       
| ... |  subjectf |       
------------------       

-- stats --
-----------------------------------
| user_id | subject_id | correct  |
-----------------------------------
|  1      |    1      |   false  |
|  1      |    1      |   false  | 
|  1      |    2      |   false  |
|  4      |    3      |   false  |
|  4      |    4      |   false  |
|  4      |    5      |   false  |
|  2      |    1      |    true  |
|  2      |    1      |    true  |
|  2      |    2      |    false |
|  2      |    2      |    true  |
|  2      |    3      |    false |
---------------------------------
```

What I need, for example for a give `user_id` (like 2), to get ALL the subjects (from subjects table) and for the ones he do (from stats) the count of correct true/false like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  id  | name     |  correct true | correct false|
----------------------------------|----------------  
|  1  |  subjecta |       2       |       0      |
|  2  |  subjectb |       1       |       1      |  
|  3  |  subjectc |       0       |       1      |  
|  4  |  subjectd |       0       |       0      | 
|  5  |  subjecte |       0       |       0      | 
|  6  |  subjectf |       0       |       0      | 
|  7  |  subjectg |       0       |       0      | 
|  8  |  subjecth |       0       |       0      | 
|  9  |  subjecte |       0       |       0      | 
| ... |  subjectf |       0       |       0      | 
----------------------------------|--------------|
```

I have no idea what to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a join between your two tables, along with some conditional aggregation to tally the number of true and false answers.

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.correct = 'true'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS correct_true,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.correct = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS correct_false
FROM subjects t1
LEFT JOIN stats t2
    ON t1.id = t2.subject_id AND
       t2.user_id = 2
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name
```

Comment: Seems like they want a `LEFT JOIN` because they want to return all subjects for a user even if there are no stats.

Comment: thanks a lot for the fast answer. as ollie says this return only row from subjects where user have stats. i want all rows from subjects. 
I try to change to `SELECT
    t2.id,
    t2.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.correct = 'true'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS correct_true,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.correct = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS correct_false
FROM subjects t2
LEFT JOIN stats t1
    ON  t2.id = t1.subject_id
WHERE t1.user_id = 2
GROUP BY t2.id, t2.name` but same thing

Comment: @AlainIb Do a `LEFT JOIN` from `subjects` to `stats`.  This should ensure that every subject always appears for each individual user you choose.  Sorry, but both Rextester and SQLFiddle are having issues right now, so I could not do any testing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Move the `WHERE` to the JOIN condition and it should work - http://rextester.com/FWVVN76539  The WHERE filter by `userid` is enforcing an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select subjects.id, subjects.name, coalesce(t.correct_true, 0), coalesce(t.correct_false, 0)
from subjects
left join (
SELECT
    subject_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN correct = 'true'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS correct_true,
    SUM(CASE WHEN correct = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS correct_false
    FROM stats
    where user_id = 2
    group by subject_id
) t
on subjects.id = t.subject_id
```